# Go back to an earlier version in tfs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I think that I have somehow screwed up my install project because my application fails during the installation project. So I would like to revert to an earlier version. My solution consists of 47 different projects and it actually works fine after installation, so I would like to keep the changes that was made after I screwed up the installation process. How do I go back to an earlier version in Team Foundation Server for a single project only?

All I know is that I have a working version from 03.03.2011 at 13:00 and a non working version at 03.03.2011 at 16:00. Please help me isolate the affected files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you get get a specific version to overwrite your workspace with earlier versions of everything (by change set number, date/time or label). This would be a good place to start: verify that the earlier version works first (even if you recall it works it is always worth verifying). In Team Explorer right click for the Get Specific Version... command. From the command line the [`tf.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56f7w6be%28VS.90%29.aspx) syntax allows specifying change set etc. (see the documentation for details).

Once you know you want to roll back one or more change sets you need to use the [rollback](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2005/11/16/493401.aspx) command from the TFS PowerToys ([download link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBD14EEA-781F-45A1-8C46-9F6BA2F68BF0&displaylang=en)) command line tool `tftp.exe` (in TFS2010 this is part of [`tf.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776.aspx)).